# Validation Error in domain modeling, Grails

Tags: validation, grails, groovy

I have two domain classes:

**User**:

```
class User {
    String login
    String password

    static belongsTo = [company: Company]
    static hasMany = [holidays: Holiday]

    static constraints = {
        company(nullable:false)
    }
}
```

**Company**:

```
class Company {
    String shortName;
    String name 
    Date dateCreated
    String region
    String email
    Address address
    Status status   
    Long tel
    Long fax

    static hasMany = [ users : User]

    static constraints = {
        name(nullable:false, size:6..20, unique:true)
        shortName(size:2..10, nullable: true, unique:true)
        region(nullable: true)
        email(email:true)
        tel(nullable: false, blank:false)
        fax(blank:false)
        address(nullable: false)
        status(nullable: false)
        users(nullable:true)
    }

    static mapping = {
        address lazy: false
        status lazy: false
    }
}
```

I have defined a one-many relationship between `User` and `Company`. And if I write the test like this :

```
void testCompanyHasManyUser() {
    def user1 = new User(login:"anto", password:"secret")
    assert user1.save(failOnError: true)
    def company1 = new Company(shortName:"helloworld",name:"helloasd",region:"chennai",
        email:"xxxyyyy@gmail.com",tel:23234,fax:343343, address: new 
        Address(country:"india",city:"chennai",street:"thayarst",code:"1233"),
        status: new Status(name:"FIXED"))
    assert company1.save()
    company1.addToUsers(user1)
}
```

When I run the test I'm getting the error like this:

```
    Validation Error(s) occurred during save(): - Field error in object 'mnm.User' on field 'company': rejected value [null]; codes [mnm.User.company.nullable.error.mnm.User.company,mnm.User.company.nullable.error.company,mnm.User.company.nullable.error.mnm.Company,mnm.User.company.nullable.error,user.company.nullable.error.mnm.User.company,user.company.nullable.error.company,user.company.nullable.error.mnm.Company,user.company.nullable.error,mnm.User.company.nullable.mnm.User.company,mnm.User.company.nullable.company,mnm.User.company.nullable.mnm.Company,mnm.User.company.nullable,user.company.nullable.mnm.User.company,user.company.nullable.company,user.company.nullable.mnm.Company,user.company.nullable,nullable.mnm.User.company,nullable.company,nullable.mnm.Company,nullable]; arguments [company,class mnm.User]; default message [Property [{0}] of class [{1}] cannot be null]
grails.validation.ValidationException: Validation Error(s) occurred during save():
- Field error in object 'mnm.User' on field 'company': rejected value [null]; codes [mnm.User.company.nullable.error.mnm.User.company,mnm.User.company.nullable.error.company,mnm.User.company.nullable.error.mnm.Company,mnm.User.company.nullable.error,user.company.nullable.error.mnm.User.company,user.company.nullable.error.company,user.company.nullable.error.mnm.Company,user.company.nullable.error,mnm.User.company.nullable.mnm.User.company,mnm.User.company.nullable.company,mnm.User.company.nullable.mnm.Company,mnm.User.company.nullable,user.company.nullable.mnm.User.company,user.company.nullable.company,user.company.nullable.mnm.Company,user.company.nullable,nullable.mnm.User.company,nullable.company,nullable.mnm.Company,nullable]; arguments [company,class mnm.User]; default message [Property [{0}] of class [{1}] cannot be null]

    at mnm.UserIntegrationTests.testCompanyHasManyUser(UserIntegrationTests.groovy:21)
```

I know I have made an error in `validation` part. Even though I'm saving the `company` object, the error shows that the `user.save` fails. Why? Where did I gowrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem looks to be that you say users must have a company, then create a user with no company and try to save it.

Try setting a company before calling

```
assert user1.save(failOnError: true)
```

However, you have shown the test for `testCompanyHasManyUser`, and the error from `testUserAddingHoliday`, so it's hard to be sure

Comment: Cool, the problem remains the same, you can't save a user with no company as you have a validation `company(nullable:false)`.  Either relax the validation, or if it is right, add the company to the user before saving the user in the test

Comment: Ya, now it works. The thing I got confused is with the validation part, even if I remove the validation `company(nullable:false)` part, I'm getting the same error as before. Any idea of why its going wrong?

Comment: if something `belongsTo` something else, that cannot be `null`

Comment: oh thanks a lot. Thats where I struck in! thanks for the answer sir...*_*